# Multithreading correctly done?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I rarely write multithreaded code, and am on shaky ground when doing so.  I make mistakes.  I would like a sanity check of something I am going to introduce in one of my apps.

There will be exactly one running instance of the `Thread` class below in my application.  (It will be stored in a servlet context attribute.)  "Clients" will call one of three methods on the instance, `getRunList()` to get data from it, `signalFreshRunListCreation()` to tell the thread to generate new data, and `stopThread()` to signal the thread to exit.  On its own, the thread creates new data every 30 seconds.

Have I made any errors?

```
public class ThreadRunListDefault extends Thread {

    // This set to true signals that the thread should exit.
    private boolean _boStop = false;
    // The thread sets this to true just before it sleeps.
    private boolean _boIsSleeping = false;
    // An external client sets this to true to signal that a new run list should  be created.
    private boolean _boFreshRunListRequested = false;
    // This is a mutex to lock the run list while a fresh one is being created.
    private Object _lockRunList = new Object();
    // This is the actual data that will be returned.
    private List<BeanRunOutput> _runList;
    // This is the time the thread will sleep between refreshing the data on its own
    private long _iSleepMilliseconds = 30000;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // Loop as long as no client has indicated the thread should stop. 
        while (!_boStop) {
            // Create the data.
            this.createFreshRunList();

            // Only sleep if a refresh of the data wasn't requested while we were 
            // creating a fresh run list.
            if (!_boFreshRunListRequested) {
                try {
                    // We set the sleeping flag to true so that signalFreshRunListCreation() will 
                    // know whether or not to call interrupt() on the thread and wake it up.
                    _boIsSleeping = true;
                    Thread.sleep(_iSleepMilliseconds);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
                _boIsSleeping = false;
            } 
        }
    }

    /*
     * This is the method that will be called by run() to create new data in the _runList member variable.
     */
    private void createFreshRunList() {
        synchronized(this._lockRunList) {
            // Here we put the code that creates the run list.  
            // Typically it will take 5 to 10 seconds.
            _runList = new ArrayList<BeanRunOutput>();
        }
    }

    /*
     * This is the method a client will call to get the data in _runList.
     */
    public List<BeanRunOutput> getRunList() {
        synchronized(this._lockRunList) {
            return _runList;
        }
    }

    /*
     * This is the method a client will call to signal the thread that a new run list should be created.
     * If run() is currently gathering data (_boIsSleeping is false), a flag will be set to tell run() 
     * to run again immediately after it is finished, without sleeping first.  If the thread is currently
     * sleeping, it will be interrupted. 
     */
    public void signalFreshRunListCreation() {
        if (_boIsSleeping) {
            // Thread is sleeping so interrupt it.
            this.interrupt();
        } else {
            // The thread is running so signal it should just run again when 
            // complete (in other words not sleep).
            _boFreshRunListRequested = true;
        }
    }

    /*
     * This method allows a client to signal the thread to exit.
    */
    public void stopThread() {
        _boStop = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

1. The  `_boStop` and the `_boIsSleeping` fields are accessed by multiple threads, so you should synchronize them. You could use `volatile` fields or `AtomicBoolean`s too.

   Make sure that you do read operations in `synchronized` blocks too, not just writes:

   > [...] synchronization has no effect unless both read and write operations are synchronized.

   From *Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 66: Synchronize access to shared mutable data*.
2. A possible bug: `_boFreshRunListRequested` is never set to `false`.
3. Using `_` prefixes (and sometimes `this.`) to access fields it's not really necessary and it's just noise. Modern IDEs use highlighting to separate local variables from instance variables.
4. You could eliminate some comments, for example:

   ```
   // Loop as long as no client has indicated the thread should stop.
   while (!boStop) {
   ```

   This could be

   ```
   while (!threadStop) {
   ```

   Another example:

   ```
      // Create the data.
      this.createFreshRunList();
   ```

   Here you could rename the method to `createData` or `createFreshData`.

   A good reading in this topic is *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin* and *Code Complete*, 2nd Edition by *Steve McConnell*.
5. It mainly depends on your requirements, but I'd consider renaming the class to `DataRefresherImpl` and implementing two interfaces: `DataRefresherService` and  `DataRefresher`. The first would be used only in the servlet/container initializer. The second is for the clients to get their data and to request new data creation. It would prevent clients to call the `stopThread` method accidentally.
6. *OldCurmudgeon* has already mentioned the `getRunList` method is dangerous. You could use [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) here. Furthermore, make sure that the `BeanRunOutput` objects are also immutable or handle the modifications. See also: *Effective Java, 2nd Edition*, *Item 39: Make defensive copies when needed*

Finally, here is an refactored version with the queue which was suggested by *OldCurmudgeon*.

```
public interface DataRefresherService {
    void shutdown();
}
```

```
public interface DataRefresher {
    List<BeanRunOutput> getRunList();
    void signalFreshRunListCreation();
}
```

```
public class DataRefresherImpl implements Runnable, 
        DataRefresherService, DataRefresher {

    private final AtomicBoolean threadStop = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private final ReentrantReadWriteLock listLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    private static final long REFRESH_INTERVAL_IN_MILLIS = 3000;

    private final ArrayBlockingQueue<String> refreshQueue = 
        new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(1);

    private List<BeanRunOutput> runList;

    public DataRefresherImpl() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!threadStop.get()) {
            createFreshRunList();
            sleepAndWakeOnRequest();
        }
    }

    private void createFreshRunList() {
        listLock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            runList = new ArrayList<BeanRunOutput>();
        } finally {
            listLock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    private void sleepAndWakeOnRequest() {
        try {
            refreshQueue.poll(REFRESH_INTERVAL_IN_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<BeanRunOutput> getRunList() {
        listLock.readLock().lock();
        try {
            return runList;
        } finally {
            listLock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void signalFreshRunListCreation() {
        refreshQueue.offer("refresh");
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {
        threadStop.set(true);
        refreshQueue.offer("shutdown");
    }
}
```

(I've not tested this too much.)

Comment: I agree with all of your points apart from 4 but let's not argue about that one here. Nice work on the queue.

Comment: I don't think `threadStop` needs to be atomic, `volatile` would do surely.

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I use your refactored version.  I'll put a comment in it with both your names.

Comment: @JohnFitzpatrick: Feel free to use it, the whole site is under creative commons licence :)

Comment: One more question:  I would like a client who has called `signalFreshRunListCreation()` while the data is currently being gathered by `createFreshRunList()` to block at least until the next `createFreshRunList()` has begun.  In other words he/she should get data from the next gathering after they call `getRunList()`.  I think all I need to do is add `listlock.readLock().lock()` and then `unlock()` immediately after `refreshQueue.offer("refresh");` to achieve this effect.  Is that true?  (OK, I know I'm going outside the scope of reviewing code.  Don't hesitate to say "we don't do that here".)

Comment: @JohnFitzpatrick: One idea: you might be able to do it with an `Executor` and submit a `Callable` which calls the `createFreshRunList` method. Then you could wait for the `Future.get` in the signal method.

Answer (score 5):

Comments in no particular order but mostly from top to bottom:

1. It is generally considered better to implement `Runnable` rather than extend `Thread`.
2. Consequently from 1, calling `this.interrupt()` is no longer valid and changing it to `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` in `signalFreshRunListCreation` highlights a problem. You will actually then be interrupting the calling thread, not the RunList thread.

   The trick to this is to store a copy of your current thread as one of the first things in your `run` method. You can then call its `interrupt()` to interrupt the RunList.
3. I am being reminded by my IDE to only `synchronize` on `final` objects. This is good advice so make `_lockRunList` `final`.
4. Just returning the list from `getRunList` is dangerous. You should probably either copy it or do something else to protect yourself from the other thread hacking it around.
5. It's probably not the best idea to use `interrupt` to control your flow. There are other mechanisms that would be better, I'd probably create a single-item `BlockingQueue` and use `poll(time)` on it to implement your pause. You can then prematurely interrupt the pause by posting to the queue.

   This would also eliminate the use of `Thread.sleep()` which is generally considered worth trying to avoid as it is rarely what you really want to do.
6. `stopThread` propably should also interrupt it. Once you are not using `interrupt` to control your flow this will become easy.
7. `boFreshRunListRequested` should be made `volatile` because it is accessed from several threads.

Just because I felt like making one, here's a `Dozer` that will pause for a certain amount of time or a special event. It uses the same mechanism we are suggesting.

```
/**
 * Use one of these to doze for a certain time.
 *
 * The dozing is fully interruptable.
 *
 * Another thread can stop the caller's doze with either a wakeup call or an abort call.
 *
 * These can be interpreted in any way you like but it is intended that a Wakeup is
 * interpreted as a normal awakening and should probably be treated in exactly the
 * same way as an Alarm. An Abort should probably be interpreted as a suggestion
 * to abandon the proces.
 */
public class Doze {
  // Special alarm messages.
  public enum Alarm {
    // Standard timeout.
    Alarm,
    // Just wake from your doze.
    Wakeup,
    // Abort the whole Doze process.
    Abort;
  }
  // My queue to wait on.
  private final ArrayBlockingQueue<Alarm> doze = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Alarm>(1);
  // How long to wait by default.
  private final long wait;

  public Doze(long wait) {
    this.wait = wait;
  }

  public Doze() {
    this(0);
  }

  public Alarm doze() throws InterruptedException {
    // Wait that long.
    return doze(wait);
  }

  public Alarm doze(long wait) throws InterruptedException {
    // Wait that long.
    Alarm poll = doze.poll(wait, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    // If we got nothing then it must be a normal wakeup.
    return poll == null ? Alarm.Alarm : poll;
  }

  public void wakeup() {
    // Just post a Wakeup.
    doze.add(Alarm.Wakeup);
  }

  public void abort() {
    // Signal the system to abort.
    doze.add(Alarm.Abort);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // Doze for 10 seconds.
    final Doze d = new Doze(1 * 1000);

    // Start a dozing thread.
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          Alarm a = d.doze();
          // Wait forever until we are aborted.
          while (a != Alarm.Abort) {
            System.out.println("Doze returned " + a);
            a = d.doze();
          }
          System.out.println("Doze returned " + a);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          // Just exit on interrupt.
        }
      }
    }).start();

    // Wait for a few seconds.
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    // Wake it up.
    d.wakeup();

    // Wait for a few seconds.
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    // Abort it.
    d.abort();


  }
}
```

Comment: All your points are crystal clear thanks.  There's just one, point 2, that I'd like to make sure I understood correctly.  Point 2 is that in its current state (even before I switch to implementing `Runnable` rather than extending `Thread`), my `signalFreshRunListCreation()` method will not have the desired effect.  The call to `this.interrupt()` does not interrupt the (possibly) sleeping thread that is executing the `run()` method, but rather it wakes the (non-sleeping) calling thread?

Comment: Not quite - if you extend `Thread` then `this.interrupt()` is a perfectly acceptable mechanism (I think). However, once you move away from extending `Thread` and merely implement `Runnable` (the "correct" mechanism) you have to take and hold a reference to the thread to access it. However, see 5 and @palacsint's example of how to avoid using `interrupt` completely.